# Pip within an erb template

Tags: python, ruby, chef-infra, erb

I have a list of chef templates that are being dropped like so:

```
scripts.each do |script|
    template "#{dir}/{script}.py" do 
         variables({ "keys" => keys })
    end
end
```

Each template outputs a python script.  One of these scripts has a pip requirement.  Since the scripts that we run change from server to server, I can't simply pip install this on all the servers.  I tried doing this:

```
<%
python_pip "python-dateutil" do 
    virtualenv "/path/to/env"
    version "2.2"
end
%>
from dateutil import parser
```

However, this sort of thing isn't possible within a chef template, chef complains that `python_pip` isn't a real method.  What is the best, most elegant, cheffy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Make scripts a hash like:

```
{
  'script1.py' => [],
  'script2.py' => %w{dep1 dep2},
}.each do |script, deps|
  deps.each do |dep|
    python_pip dep do
      #stuff
    end
  end
  template "#{dir}/{script}.py" do 
    variables({ "keys" => keys })
  end
end
```

This keeps all the logic in the recipe where it belongs.